# What characters are these scantily-clad guys cosplaying as?

Tags: cosplay

Possibly NSFW (Contains near nude guys)

> [image]

Does anybody knows what anime these costumes are from, and what characters they are for? Is this even from an anime?

Comment: could be guys cosplaying Nudist Beach organization from Kill la Kill

Answer (score 6):

The anime is from Kill la Kill made by trigger studio.

The guy on the left is Inumata in his nudist beach costume:
[image]

The guy on the right is Mikisugi in his nudist beach costume:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's Kill la Kill. Inumuta (left) and Mikisugi (right).